# Hibernate mapping saving issue

Tags: java, hibernate

У меня есть две проблемных сущности:
Первая:

```
public class User implements UserDetails {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8442780593066407492L;
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "user_role",
            joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "user_id")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "role_id")})
    private Set<UserRole> userRoles = new HashSet<UserRole>();

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
    private Set<CommentReserv> comments = new HashSet<CommentReserv>();

    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        List<SimpleGrantedAuthority> result = new 
        ArrayList<SimpleGrantedAuthority>();
        for (UserRole userRole: userRoles) {
            result.add(new 
            SimpleGrantedAuthority(userRole.getListRole().name()));
            }
        return result;
    }
...
}
```

Вторая:

```
public class CommentReserv implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1579363480188238317L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "reservation_id")
    private Reservation reservation;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User user;
...
}
```

В контроллере я получаю данные из БД:

```
Reservation reservation = this.reservationRepository.getReservationById(params.get("reservationId").toString());            
User currentUser = this.userRepository.getUser(principal.getName());
```

До данного момента все нормально. User.getId() возвращает 0 (у меня единственная записть в БД).
Далее:

```
commentReserv.setReservation(reservation);
commentReserv.setComment(params.get("comment").toString());
commentReserv.setUser(currentUser);
```

После этого я сохраняю полученное в БД(.save(comment)). При этом в БД создается копия!!! User с новым id и его id ставится в соответствующее поле сохраненного CommentReserv. Кроме этого, все остальное сохраняется корректно и ошибок не возникает. Помогите разгадать загадку.

Upd:Если убрать cascade из CommentReserv, то возникает "TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance beforeQuery flushing: com...domain.User]"

Comment: `CascadeType.ALL` на обоих сторонах, если сохраняете юзера и у него есть комментарии, то сохранится юзер и все его комментарии (у всех id 0). Так же само и обратно, при сохранении комментария с юзером (id 0 у всех), то сохранится комментарий и юзер.

Comment: @MrFylypenko, попробовал изменить у юзера cascade на CascadeType.ALL. Теже чудеса.

Comment: `User currentUser = this.userRepository.getUser(principal.getName());` что возвращает этот метод? Там должен быть currentUser с `id != 0` и после  сохранения в БД у комментария будет проставлен id этого пользователя. Если каскада нет, то хибернейт на это и ругнется, а если каскад есть, то создаст нового пользователя и в комментарии проставит ИД созданного пользователя.

Comment: @MrFylypenko, он возвращает currentUser с id = 0. То есть по идее, он не должен создавать нового.

Comment: Если возвращает с id 0, то его не существует в БД, это сигнал гибернейту сохранить нового пользователя (при включенном каскаде). Нужно указать какому юзеру принадлежить комментарий или оставить `null` , тогда в БД у комментария не будет пользователя.

Comment: У меня в БД есть пользователь с id=0 (он там всего один и авторизация через него работает).

Comment: Хибернейт не понимает сущности с id=0, он думает, что она не сохранена в БД. Попробуй поменять на id=1 и запустить свой код.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема оказалась в том, что Hibernate воспринимает сущность с id=0 как не существующую в базе и добавлял новую, а в моей БД хранился всего один пользователь у которого id как раз был 0. Я поменял в БД id этого пользователя на 1 и все заработало.
Спасибо @MrFylypenko за правильный совет.